# Textbox value return null in bootstrap template asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net, bootstrap-4

Scenario:
I have used bootstrap template in asp.net and trying to update the textbox value.
The page is in the child page of a master page and I have tried using EnableviewState Property to true/false both ways.

Problem:
I am not getting the value of textbox on a codebehind on click of a button.

Code used: ASPX:

```
<div class="form-actions"> 
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtAccountName_English" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" runat="Server">
            Save</button>
</div>
```

and Code Behind:

```
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    cmd.Connection = New SqlConnection(constr)
    cmd.CommandText = "usp_Set_Accounts"
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure 
    cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("AccountName_English", txtAccountName_English.Text))
```

Please tell me what is the issue here.

Comment: You mentioned "trying to update the textbox value" so what does that mean? On which event you are trying to read the textbox value?

Comment: Hi, I am trying to populate the value from db on a click of button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After 2 days of searching.. I found the solution.. there were 2 "form" tags in the master page which was causing the issue. I removed one and it worked for me.. I dont have the exact explanation as why with multiple forms it was not working..

thanks all for your responses..